# How to show Hero Animation on a NetworkImage while switching from one screen to another?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project, in one screen I show some list of data(including image) from API call. In that list I have wrapped the **NetworkImage** with **Hero** and added the productId as the tag.

Here's the code-

```
            Expanded(
              child: Hero(
                tag: '${snapshot.data[position].products[index].id}',
                child: FadeInImage(
                  width: 130.0,
                  height: 186.0,
                  placeholder: AssetImage('assets/placeholder.jpg'),
                  image:     
                NetworkImage(snapshot.data[position].products[index].image),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

While **switching to next screen**, I pass the entire object which I get from API which following code-

```
Navigator.of(context)
    .push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ProductDetailsScreen(
            snapshot.data[position].products[index])));
```

Now, in next Screen(where I have passed the entire object product), I have wrapped my **NetworkImage** with Hero and used the **products.id** as tag.

Here's the code-

```
 Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: ScreenUtil.instance.setHeight(15)),
          child: Hero(
            tag: '${products.id}',
            child: FadeInImage(
              height: ScreenUtil.instance.setHeight(330),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              placeholder: AssetImage('assets/placeholder.jpg'),
              image: NetworkImage(
                "${products.image}",
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**Now the problem is** ------

After running the project, when I press one item from the list(where the NetworkImage includes), it shows black in the next screen and showing the following error in the console-

[image]

I have followed the same way described in some documentation that each items for animation should have the same tag name, but in my case it is not working. Showing that-

> There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

So, I need a solution to solve this issue.

Comment: do you have the the same hero twice on either of the pages?

Comment: Yes, I have the same hero with same tag in two different classes.

Comment: I know that part, but allow me to clarify, on either of the pages is there a duplicate of the same hero? It's telling you that you are passing the same id to multiple hero widgets, so either you likely have a duplicate ID somewhere or there could be another hero on the same screen that's a duplicate of the ones listed here.

Comment: Another element in that screen has same id but that is not wrapped with Hero. My each class has only one Hero widget.

Comment: and you're certain that your product ID is unique? Something else you could do is generate an id for each item with something like https://pub.dev/packages/uuid 

Then pass that id to your navigated page as the herotag argument.

Comment: You could also use the product object's hashcode for a quick test. If that works I wouldn't use the hashcode in the long term because it could potentially produce duplicates.

Comment: Tried your suggested  pub.dev/packages/uuid  solution , but showing the same error.

Comment: I think more code would be helpful to diagnose the underlying issue. Namely how you're building the initial product widget and what it's contained in. The UUID failing (assuming you created an ID for each product) means that there is probably a duplicate widget being built somewhere.

Comment: Do me a favor, remove the hero tag on the next screen. Does it work as expected?

Comment: If I set static value in my hero tag for both screens will it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200970/discussion-between-adrian-murray-and-s-m-asif).

Comment: @AdrianMurray, I solved it. I was using  **${snapshot.data[position].products[index].id}** as the hero tag, but I passed the entire object to next screen. So, rather using only id as tag , I had to use the the object-  **snapshot.data[position].products[index]**  for the hero tag for first screen & object - **products** for the Second screen and the problem is solved. Thanks for your kind corporation.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the case but I didn't look into the next page. Cheers

Comment: @S.M.Asif could you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Save Network image file to a File variable then pass it throw pages (u can use file path as tag for hero and use file)

Retrieve data from ur database save to URL variable in my case it is just 'String url'(I'm getting it from another widget so I used widget.url)

from 1st screen

```
Hero(
  tag: 'anything' + widget.url,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: widget.url!= null
                                ? ExtendedNetworkImageProvider(
                                    widget.url,
                                  )
                                : null,
                            radius: 23,
                          ),

Navigator.of(context).push(TransparentRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondScreen(
                              image: widget.url,
                            )));
```

(image URL is unique so we can use it as tag for hero)

2nd screen

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final image;

  
  SecondScreen(
      {this.image});
  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}
```

```
    Hero(
      tag: 'anything' + widget.image,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: widget.image!= null
                                    ? ExtendedNetworkImageProvider(
                                        widget.image
                                      )
                                    : null,
                                radius: 23,
                              ),
```